# Discord.js: MessageCollector, messages doesn't trigger collect event

Tags: javascript, discord.js, collectors

I'm trying to code a giveaway bot in discord.js, it is the first time that I code in Javascript so if you have any recommendations I would be happy to hear them !

I am trying to launch a giveaway on a specific channel, the channel is usually locked for @everyone, when the giveaway starts, I open the channel and start listening for inputs.

I would like to listen for every messages, check if it is a correct ethereum wallet, if it is, gather it, if it is not, delete the message from the channel.

I wanted to use a `createMessageCollector` **without** any filter, and manually check everything. However, messages doesn't trigger the `collect` event..

Here is the code:

```
async function launch_giveaway(interaction) {
    const giveawayChannel = interaction.options.getChannel("in");
    const giveawayName = interaction.options.getString("name");
    const numWinner = interaction.options.getInteger("num_winners");
    const hours = interaction.options.getInteger("hours");
    const minutes = interaction.options.getInteger("minutes");
    const channelWinner = interaction.options.getChannel("winner_channel")

    let endTime = Math.round(Date.now()/1000) + hours*3600 + minutes*60;
    await interaction.reply(`Starting the giveaway of **${giveawayName}** in ${giveawayChannel} for ${hours}:${minutes}, I will put the ${numWinner} winners in ${channelWinner} !`);
    await open_giveaway(interaction, giveawayChannel, giveawayName, numWinner, endTime, channelWinner)
    await interaction.followUp(`Done ! ${giveawayChannel} is now open and members can send there wallets !`);

    setTimeout(close_channel, hours*3600000 + minutes*60000, interaction, giveawayChannel, channelWinner, giveawayName);
    let wallets = [];

    const filter = m => {return true;};
    const collector = giveawayChannel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });

    collector.on('collect', m => {
        console.log("someone typed in #giveaway");
        // check ethereum wallet regex etc
        // add to wallets list
    });

    collector.on('end', collected => {
        console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} wallets`);
    });
}
```

I even tested with the default code from [this tutorial](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-component-collector), but it doesn't log anything on my console.

Thank you very much for your help,

Chronoxx

Comment: I copy-pasted just your collector code into my own bot (starting from the line with `filter`, and ending with `collector.on('end')`), and that part is working perfectly fine. Are you sure the value of `giveawayChannel` is correct? Does the `"Collected x wallets"` statement log after 15 seconds? Is the collector code even reached at all (maybe try putting a `console.log` right before the collector and see if it ever runs)? Since the collector code itself is working, your issue must be something else or something indirectly related.

Comment: I just added a log before the `collector.on("collect")` and it worked perfectly, the log on the `collector.on("end")` also worked, it outputs `Collected 0 wallets` ... In the `open_giveaway` function that you see in my code, I do `giveawayChannel.send(...)` and it sends a message properly on the Giveaway channel... Is it allowed to put a filter that allows all entries like this?

Comment: Yes, any filter function works for these collectors. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, I tested your collector code and it was working for me. Not sure what would be causing your issue. Perhaps try creating just a classic `client.on("message")` handler and see if that is detecting any messages? The collectors use `client.on("message")` behind the scenes, so if the message event can't detect messages, that would be the issue.